# I accidently removed the libs folder under app module, how to restore it?

Tags: android, android-studio

**Problem:** The libs folder under app module was empty. I was trying to add a jar to the libs folder, then when i tried to remove it, but removed the whole libs folder. To make this up, I created a new folder called libs in the same place, but the new folder doesn't show in the hierarchy. But I can find it in the file browser.
Now when I reopen the project, I get a error:

```
Error:(1958, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'metaButtonBarButtonStyle'.
```

**Question:** Will the missing of the libs folder have ant influence on my project? Is this resource not found error caused by missing the libs folder?

Comment: why not create a new project with all the same settings as your current one and copy the libs folder over from the new one to your current one

Comment: I recommend doing what @Ryan just said

Comment: I tried what @Ryan said and it's good! Many thanks! The error is still there, but the folder is back.